# Postdoc vs Assistant Prof - which is better for a career academic?

Tags: postdocs, tenure-track, biology, medicine

All questions are hypothetical as of now.

I work in the health / biomedical sciences. I have been a postdoc for about 2.5 years and had to leave the postdoc after the lab closed. I have been interviewing for both junior faculty and postdoc positions for the last 3 months but none have worked out (pay cut, rejection etc)

I have an upcoming postdoc fellowship interview with X lab in University A, which I applied for towards the end of the application deadline 1st week Feb. The independent academic committee has determined I am fully qualified for the position and no rebuttals were needed (unusual I know; this is a Scandinavian university). This is a position that will take me out of my comfort zone and give the opportunity to develop new quantitative skills - if the mentors are good (YKWIM). This project is supervised by 2 mentors and both have very impressive h-indices, and one very experienced researcher and another younger researcher but very impressive credentials. I will have teaching responsibilities.

However I applied for an asst prof position in Y lab/dept in the **same uni** A, which has a much later application deadline. I believe I have a good chance of getting this gig because I have run many projects in this exact area of research and have all the training and certifications needed. I guess I won't be developing any more technical skills and moving on to project management / teaching / administration. This is unique as the position already comes with a project and a longer term of employment, and is still supervised by 1 prof. The yearly salary is not much different from the postdoc and the potential impact of the research is lower.

The academic's goal is to get a faculty position but it seems the asst prof position would be of little value since this is not my grant. It is also not clear if this is a tenure track position.

Hoping I could get some advice from more experienced researchers because my focus  is on building a career, although I do hope to make great scientific achievements in the process.

Cheers and I'll be hanging around if anyone has questions.

Comment: I am surprised - to my knowledge assistant professorships in Scandinavia are typically tenure-track. Source: I am an assistant professor in Sweden.

Comment: Are you sure that the second one is a position of assistant professor? I've never heard of an assistant professor being supervised by another academic. Also the fact that it's with a specific topic and duration makes it look more like a postdoc position.

Comment: @Erwan yeah I've read the job posting many times..it does look like a postdoc but it's for an asst prof. I had to submit a research plan and teaching statement. The paygrade appears to be the same as that of an experienced postdoc.

Comment: *If* you want to quote from or link to the job announcement, that would help with figuring out what is going on. No pressure, of course.

Comment: @TommiBrander This question being hypothetical, let's assume the said job ad IS for an asst prof. How important is a title for long term job prospects, all things equal?

Comment: @FrostedCentral afaik being assistant professor is supposed to be more advanced in the career ladder, so it's more prestigious. On the other hand, when your contract ends people might assume that something went wrong, especially if assistant professor are usually tenure track in the country. It looks a bit weird to me, normally the title corresponds to a specific status in the academic hierarchy. But I'm not in Scandinavia, it might be a local thing.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, I think it would be clear that the assistant professorship is preferable to a post doc in nearly every case. The exception would be the opportunity to work with a superstar as a post doc.

Again, in the US, assistant professorships are (almost) invariably tenure track, though there are a very few colleges that don't offer tenure at all. But that isn't likely to be a factor.

For most, a post doc is really just considered to be a stepping stone to a real position and a way to continue to advance if the job market is poor at the time.

But ask the institution itself about tenure and also about the likelihood of actually earning it.